# Need advice: what should be my next step for solving the derivative of $f(z)$ using the definition?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

What should be my next step for solving the derivative of $f(z)$ using the definition?

$$f(z) = (2{z^2} + 1) \cdot ({z^3} - \sqrt {z}) $$

$$f'(z) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\vartriangle z \to 0} \frac{{f(z + \vartriangle z) - f(z)}}{{\vartriangle z}} \\= \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\vartriangle z \to 0} \frac{{[2{{(z + \vartriangle z)}^2} + 1] \cdot [{{(z + \vartriangle z)}^3} - \sqrt {(z + \vartriangle z)} ] - (2{z^2} + 1) \cdot ({z^3} - \sqrt {z}) }}{{\vartriangle z}}$$

At this point I don't know how to proceed: when I try to expand it,  I can't isolate the ∆z to simplify and avoid the division by zero. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to solve this only using the definition?

Comment: Yes, I'm learning complex analysis and the book gives several simple examples, but when I try the exercises I'm stuck. I'm assuming there is something obvious that I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Personally, I would never try to compute such a limit using the definition, since it's so much easier to prove smaller results (power rule, sum rule, product rule) and piece them together. You're right that expanding the limit definition is so messy that it seems impossible!

Comment: Can you say exactly where you're getting this exercise (what book and what exercise number)? It could help determine what sorts of methods you should be applying.

Comment: You are probably right, maybe I'm supposed to use the product rule, from what I can tell it's not holomorphic at 0.

Comment: Observe that the question does not need any ideas from complex analysis. Use a little bit algebraic manipulation and calculate the limit. In case you are aware of proof of limit laws the algebraic manipulation is easy. For example you can add and subtract $(2(z+\Delta z) ^2+1))(z^3-\sqrt{z})$ in numerator and split it into two terms.

Comment: You may try to work it out using approach suggested in last comment and update your post by adding your attempt. Also the discussion in comments (like your background of learning complex analysis and probably source of the problem) can be added to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After distributing the terms we have...

$$ f(z) = (2{z^2} + 1) \cdot ({z^3} - \sqrt {z}) = 2z^5 - 2z^{
\frac{5}{2}} + z^3 - z^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

by definition of derivative...

$$ f'(z) = \lim _{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{f(z+\Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z} $$

$$ = \lim _{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{2{(z+\Delta z)}^5 - 2(z+\Delta z)^{\frac{5}{2}} + (z+\Delta z)^3 - (z+\Delta z)^{\frac{1}{2}} - \Big[ 2z^5 - 2z^{
\frac{5}{2}} + z^3 - z^{\frac{1}{2}} \Big]}{\Delta z} $$

$$ = \lim _{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{2{(z+\Delta z)}^5 - 2(z+\Delta z)^{\frac{5}{2}} + (z+\Delta z)^3 - (z+\Delta z)^{\frac{1}{2}} - 2z^5 + 2z^{
\frac{5}{2}} - z^3 + z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\Delta z} $$

You can proceed by factoring out the larger powers; solving for limits; and then factoring a $\Delta z$ from the remaining terms in the numerator. At that point, the $\Delta z$ in the numerator will cancel the one in the denominator, and you will be left with the answer. However, it is **much** easier to obtain the result using the standard differentiation rules, all of which can be proven using the definition of a limit. Otherwise, you are faced with the tedious task of computing an enormous polynomial.

For example, using standard differentation rules...

$$ f'(z) = \frac{d}{dz} f(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \Big[ 2z^5 - 2z^{
\frac{5}{2}} + z^3 - z^{\frac{1}{2}} \Big] $$

by the sum and difference rules we have

$$ = \frac{d}{dz} 2z^5 - \frac{d}{dz} 2z^{
\frac{5}{2}} + \frac{d}{dz} z^3 - \frac{d}{dz} z^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

by the constant multiple rule we have

$$ = 2 \frac{d}{dz} z^5 - 2 \frac{d}{dz} z^{
\frac{5}{2}} + \frac{d}{dz} z^3 - \frac{d}{dz} z^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

and by the power rule we have

$$ = 2 \cdot 5z^{(5-1)} - 2 \cdot  \frac{5}{2} z^{(
\frac{5}{2} - 1)} + 3 \cdot z^{(3-1)} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot z^{(\frac{1}{2}-1)} $$

and then we clean things up...

$$ = 10z^4 - 5z^{\frac{3}{2}} + 3z^2 - \frac{1}{2} z^{-\frac{1}{2}} $$

$$ = 10z^4 - 5z\sqrt{z} + 3z^2 - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}} $$

If you have any doubts about all of this, then I suggest reviewing the proofs of the standard differentiation rules. In particular, prove the sum/difference rule, the constant multiple rule, and power rule for any arbitrary function, using the definition of derivative. Then you will have confidence in this result without having to explicitly prove it from the ground up. You can find proof of said rules [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/DerivativeProofs.aspx).